# Build OpenSSL 1.1.0 for Windows UWP

Tags: uwp, openssl, cross-platform, windows-community-toolkit

I am able to build openssl 1.1.0v for win64 and win32. But facing problems to build for ARM architecure.

> **AIM** : I want to build an Universal Windows platform application that runs on all devices( x64, x86 and ARM).

For Win32, following are the commands.

1. perl Configure VC-WIN32 --prefix=C:\openssl-1.1.0c_x86
2. nmake
3. nmake test
4. nmake install

For Win64, following are the commands.

1. perl Configure VC-WIN64 --prefix=C:\openssl-1.1.0c_x64
2. nmake
3. nmake test
4. nmake install

For ARM, what **argument to pass to perl Configure**?

Comment: `VC-WIN32` is not correct for ARM. You should probably just use Microsoft's port of OpenSSL at [Microsoft GitHub | OpenSSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/openssl). Its a fork of OpenSSL's GitHub. I'm not sure if OpenSSL 1.1.0 has been ported yet. I recall talk of it last winter or over the summer, but I don't recall what came of it.

Comment: Microsoft GitHub | OpenSSL uses openssl 1.0.1 which has multi-threading problems. That's why i want to cross compile openssl 1.1.0.